# Normalize a String to create a safe URL in Java

Tags: java, string, url, normalization

I'm writing a library in Java which creates the URL from a list of filenames in this way:

```
final String domain = "http://www.example.com/";

String filenames[] = {"Normal text","Ich weiß nicht", "L'ho inserito tra i princìpi"};

System.out.println(domain+normalize(filenames[0]);
//Prints  "http://www.example.com/Normal_text"
System.out.println(domain+normalize(filenames[1]);
//Prints  "http://www.example.com/Ich_weib_nicht"
System.out.println(domain+normalize(filenames[2]);
//Prints  "http://www.example.com/L_ho_inserito_tra_i_principi"
```

Exists somewhere a Java library that exposes the method `normalize` that I'm using in the code above?

Literature:

- [Which special characters are safe to use in url?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/498/which-special-characters-are-safe-to-use-in-url)
- [Safe characters for friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489289/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stringbyfoldingwithoptionslocale-in-java/21489947#21489947

Comment: @PopoFibo Yes, it works! I never seen the `Normalizer` class in Java! Thanks a lot! Can you post an answer with a short example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking the content from my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489289/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stringbyfoldingwithoptionslocale-in-java/21489947#21489947), you can use [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) which comes close to normalizing Strings in Java. An example of normalization would be;

Accent removal:

```
String accented = "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép";
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(accented,  Normalizer.Form.NFD);
normalized = normalized.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

System.out.println(normalized);
```

Gives;

```
arvizturo tukorfurogep
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean you want to encode the strings to make them safe for the url. In which case use URLEncoder:

```
final String domain = "http://www.example.com/";

String filenames[] = {"Normal text","Ich weiß nicht", "L'ho inserito tra i princìpi"};

System.out.println(domain + URLEncoder.encode(filenames[0], "UTF-8"));
System.out.println(domain + URLEncoder.encode(filenames[1], "UTF-8"));
System.out.println(domain + URLEncoder.encode(filenames[2], "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: No, because I can't use "special" chars like % and so on which comes from the `URLEncoder.encode()` method. I'm creating URLs which must be result valid byr a special XML validator. It requires no whitespaces, no special chars, and so on

Comment: So they aren't URLs then

Comment: No no, they are! The XML contains a list of elements, each element has an `rdf:about` property which has an URL as value

Comment: In which case I would use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML() from the apache commons lang library but I don't see what that has to do with URLs

Comment: That method is not ok for the validator. E.g., `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("l'avevo all'università")` is escaped as `l&apos;avevo all&apos;università`: the accented "a" is still there! Moreover, the text is not human-readable.