# Why does my text normalization behave differently in different environments?

Tags: java, string, unicode-normalization

I am normalizing some accented text using the following approach / code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489289/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stringbyfoldingwithoptionslocale-in-java/21489947#21489947)

Accent removal:

```
String accented = "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép";
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(accented,  Normalizer.Form.NFD);
normalized = normalized.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println(normalized);
```

When I run this from with IntelliJ (as part of a unit test), this gives the expected result:

```
arvizturo tukorfurogep
```

If I run this from the command line (via gradle), I get:

```
ArvAztArA tAkArfArAgA
```

In both cases, I'm using the same PC and Java `1.8.0_151`.

The relevant parts from `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

What causes this different behaviour? And how do I ensure I get the expected result everywhere?

Comment: could you please share your gradle file, because i tried same code using gradle it worked.

Comment: Question updated with `gradle` snippet.

Comment: where's the run task in your gradle ?, you running the code using a task in gradle right like this : task(runui, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'stockticker.ui.StockTickerDriver'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  }

Comment: On the command line, I type `gradle clean test`

Comment: Imagree, looks more like a compile Problem not a runtime Problem. Define your source encoding (or use Unicode escapes and ascii only in the source code)

Comment: I'll try the character encoding at compile time. The actual text is user-supplied, so I will not be able to escape it at compile time.

Comment: OK, looks like we're onto something. In IntelliJ `System.getProperty("file.encoding");` returns `UTF-8`, while on the command line, I get `windows-1252`.  Now to figure out an actual solution.

Comment: Your sample code shows a literal, it is subject to the source encoding. When you read a file don’t use the default encoding of FileReader (and show the complete code).

Comment: I don't actually read a file at any point in the real process. There's a string literal in the test code. In production, it's a string received from a browser request (hence the need to sanitise it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @eckes and others for the compile time suggestion. By specifying an encoding at compile time, I was able to get the desired result.

The setting I added to `build.gradle` was:

```
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

This option only affects the test classes (which is where my issue was). You can also use:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

if you have text in your production code that needs to be encoded.

An alternative solution I came across is:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

(Interestingly, none of the above solutions changed the value of the `file.encoding` system property.)